# Visualforce error when logged in as customer community user

Tags: visualforce, javascript, community

I have a custom VF page that uses some JS to give a different "MyProfile" page experience in a Community.  It worked fine. I logged in as a customer community user and all was well.  I made a change to the VF page to add two new  values. I save, I preview (from Dev console) and all looks fine and I can see the two new fields. Then I log in as the customer user and get an error that the page cannot be displayed.  I checked the FLS for the Customer profile and they have view access to that object and to those fields.  Any idea what I might be missing? The fields added are Contact fields which I access through dot notation (User.Contact.myfieldname).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The communities user does not have access to the User object, I don't believe, which is the problem here. You are querying and returning a user object, with some parent relationship queries and your VF page is seeing you attempting to display fields from User on your page. If you queried the Contact object directly, I suspect that this page would work.

Comment: I suspected that as well. I queried the Contact detail directly in my class and also changed the method to without sharing (from with sharing). While I don't get that error anymore, now it just hangs and exceeds the time limit.

Comment: Actually, querying the Contact caused it to work. When I checked the debug log it was looking for a few other fields in the query. Once added, all was well. Thanks!